# Lock a column based on id using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to lock a column based on it's id using jquery? I've seen different solutions, like header locking, and some can also lock the columns indexing from left. What I am trying to do is when I click the lock button, it will lock the column and won't be moved when scrolled horizontally.

For example I click the lock on header 1, scrolled horizontally, then clicked lock on header 3. Header 1 and Header 3 should be adjacent to each other and shouldn't move when scrolled horizontally.

[Click here to view image](http://imm.io/U1MR)

Below is my code:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 75%; overflow-x: scroll;">
<table style="width: 200% !important;">
    <tr>
        <td id="lid_1" colspan="3">
            <div style="margin-top: 3px;">
                January 24, 2013
                <button id="lid_1">Lock</button>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td id="lid_2" colspan="3">
            <div style="margin-top: 3px;">
                January 25, 2013
                <button id="lid_2">Lock</button>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td id="lid_3" colspan="3">
            <div style="margin-top: 3px;">
                January 26, 2013
                <button id="lid_3">Lock</button>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td id="lid_4" colspan="3">
            <div style="margin-top: 3px;">
                January 27, 2013
                <button id="lid_4">Lock</button>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td id="lid_5" colspan="3">
            <div style="margin-top: 3px;">
                January 27, 2013
                <button id="lid_5">Lock</button>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td id="lid_6" colspan="3">
            <div style="margin-top: 3px;">
                January 28, 2013
                <button id="lid_6">Lock</button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="lid_1">Header 1</td>
        <td id="lid_1">Header 2</td>
        <td id="lid_1">Header 3</td>
        <td id="lid_2">Header 1</td>
        <td id="lid_2">Header 2</td>
        <td id="lid_2">Header 3</td>
        <td id="lid_3">Header 1</td>
        <td id="lid_3">Header 2</td>
        <td id="lid_3">Header 3</td>
        <td id="lid_4">Header 1</td>
        <td id="lid_4">Header 2</td>
        <td id="lid_4">Header 3</td>
        <td id="lid_5">Header 1</td>
        <td id="lid_5">Header 2</td>
        <td id="lid_5">Header 3</td>
        <td id="lid_6">Header 1</td>
        <td id="lid_6">Header 2</td>
        <td id="lid_6">Header 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="lid_1" colspan="3">
            <table style="width:100.1%; margin-top: -17px !important; margin-left: -1px !important;">
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
                <br/>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td id="lid_2" colspan="3">
            <table style="width:100.1%; margin-top: -17px !important; margin-left: -1px !important;">
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
                <br/>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td id="lid_3" colspan="3">
            <table style="width:100.1%; margin-top: -17px !important; margin-left: -1px !important;">
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
                <br/>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td id="lid_4" colspan="3">
            <table style="width:100.1%; margin-top: -17px !important; margin-left: -1px !important;">
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
                <br/>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td id="lid_5" colspan="3">
            <table style="width:100.1%; margin-top: -17px !important; margin-left: -1px !important;">
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
                <br/>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td id="lid_6" colspan="3">
            <table style="width:100.1%; margin-top: -17px !important; margin-left: -1px !important;">
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
                <br/>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Code needed, i.e. what columns?

Comment: It would be good if you add one image, at least before all `what have  you tried` guys are on your neck :)
Just click edit and you'll see the image upload button

Comment: I don't know what elements you use as columns, but could you not try `$('#id_of_column').click(function(){$(this).css("position","fixed");});`

Comment: @kidwon page won't let me attach a photo since my 'reputation' doesn't meet the requirements for posting one.

I'll update the thread once I can attach a photo for visual reference.

Comment: Use that for instance http://imm.io/

Comment: @fricke I have tried your method but when I have clicked 2 adjacent columns, the first one was replaced by the second one. By the way, am using <td> element as column.

Comment: @kidwon thanks for the tip, I'll be using that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here's a solution to your update.
However ids are meant to be unique so you shouldn't have 2 or more same ids. Classes are the tool in general use-cases.
You may add unique ids if unique columns are required but not using them as reference in the context of locking, but extract the id when you want to do something with it.

Here are the examples:

http://jsbin.com/odaxil/5

http://jsbin.com/odaxil/5/edit

**js:**

```
(function (window, undefined) {
    jQuery(function () {
        bindings();
    });

    function bindings() {
        var locker = jQuery('#locker');
        jQuery(document).on('click', 'button.lockButton', function () {
            var that = $(this),
                lidClass = '',
                parent = that.parents('td[class^="lid"]');
            if (parent.length) {
                lidClass = getColumnLidClass(parent);
                lockings = jQuery('td.' + lidClass);
                lockings.addClass('locked');
                that.text('Unlock');
                var fixedColumn = $(getLockedWrapper(lockings, lidClass));
                var index = parent.index();
                fixedColumn.data('index', index);

                if (index === 0) {
                    locker.prepend(fixedColumn);
                } else {
                    var lockedWraps = $('div.lockedWrap', locker),
                        lwrap = null,
                        indx, appended = false;
                    if (!lockedWraps.length) locker.append(fixedColumn);
                    lockedWraps.each(function () {
                        lwrap = $(this);
                        indx = lwrap.data('index') * 1;
                        if (!appended && (index < indx)) {
                            lwrap.before(fixedColumn);
                            appended = true;
                            return;
                        }
                    });
                    if (!appended) locker.append(fixedColumn);
                }
                that.text('Lock');
            } else {
                parent = that.parents('div.lockedWrap');
                lidClass = getColumnLidClass(parent);
                lockings = jQuery('td.' + lidClass);
                lockings.removeClass('locked');
                parent.remove();
            }
        });
    }


    function getLockedWrapper(lockings, lidClass) {
        var fixedColumn = [],
            cont;
        lockings.each(function () {
            cont = $(this).html();
            fixedColumn.push('<div class="cellWrap">' + cont + '</div>');
        });
        fixedColumn = '<div class="' + lidClass + ' lockedWrap">' + fixedColumn.join('') + '</div>';
        return fixedColumn;
    }

    function getColumnLidClass(td) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            if (td.hasClass('lid_' + i)) break;
        }
        return 'lid_' + i;
    }
})();
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="locker"></div>
<div style="float: left; width: 75%; overflow-x: scroll;">
    <table style="width: 200% !important;">
        <tr>
            <td class="lid_1" colspan="3">
                <div style="margin-top: 3px;">January 24, 2013
                    <button class="lockButton" id="lid_1">Lock</button>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="lid_2" colspan="3">
                <div style="margin-top: 3px;">January 25, 2013
                    <button class="lockButton" id="lid_2">Lock</button>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="lid_3" colspan="3">
                <div style="margin-top: 3px;">January 26, 2013
                    <button class="lockButton" id="lid_3">Lock</button>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="lid_4" colspan="3">
                <div style="margin-top: 3px;">January 27, 2013
                    <button class="lockButton" id="lid_4">Lock</button>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="lid_5" colspan="3">
                <div style="margin-top: 3px;">January 27, 2013
                    <button class="lockButton" id="lid_5">Lock</button>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="lid_6" colspan="3">
                <div style="margin-top: 3px;">January 28, 2013
                    <button class="lockButton" id="lid_6">Lock</button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="lid_1">Header 1</td>
            <td class="lid_1">Header 2</td>
            <td class="lid_1">Header 3</td>
            <td class="lid_2">Header 1</td>
            <td class="lid_2">Header 2</td>
            <td class="lid_2">Header 3</td>
            <td class="lid_3">Header 1</td>
            <td class="lid_3">Header 2</td>
            <td class="lid_3">Header 3</td>
            <td class="lid_4">Header 1</td>
            <td class="lid_4">Header 2</td>
            <td class="lid_4">Header 3</td>
            <td class="lid_5">Header 1</td>
            <td class="lid_5">Header 2</td>
            <td class="lid_5">Header 3</td>
            <td class="lid_6">Header 1</td>
            <td class="lid_6">Header 2</td>
            <td class="lid_6">Header 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="lid_1" colspan="3">
                <table style="width:100.1%; margin-top: -17px !important; margin-left: -1px !important;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <br/>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td class="lid_2" colspan="3">
                <table style="width:100.1%; margin-top: -17px !important; margin-left: -1px !important;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <br/>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td class="lid_3" colspan="3">
                <table style="width:100.1%; margin-top: -17px !important; margin-left: -1px !important;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <br/>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td class="lid_4" colspan="3">
                <table style="width:100.1%; margin-top: -17px !important; margin-left: -1px !important;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <br/>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td class="lid_5" colspan="3">
                <table style="width:100.1%; margin-top: -17px !important; margin-left: -1px !important;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <br/>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td class="lid_6" colspan="3">
                <table style="width:100.1%; margin-top: -17px !important; margin-left: -1px !important;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <br/>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.locked{
  display:none;
}
#locker{
  float: left;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 110px;
  background-color: #333;
}
div.lockedWrap{
  float:left;
  margin-right:1px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK I got it.
Continuing [fricke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1201967/fricke)

approach which is fixing the column...

It seems that you need a map of fixed columns and prevent pileing on ot top of another. It's not replaced as you thought it's just that probably the newly fixed goes on top of the old one.

So you do that:

```
var fixedColumns = jQuery();
$('#id_of_column').click(function () {
    var that = $(this);
    if (that.hasClass('locked')) {
        //Unlock
        that.removeClass('locked')
            .css({'left': ''});
        fixedColumns = fixedColumns.not(that);
    } else {
        //Lock
        fixedColumns = fixedColumns.add(that);
        that.addClass('locked');
        orderLockedColumns(fixedColumns);
    }
});

function orderLockedColumns(columns) {
    var that, leftPos, prevCol, prevColWidth, prevColPos;
    columns.each(function (i) {
        that = $(this),
        leftPos = 0;
        if (i !== 0) {
            prevCol = jQuery(columns[i - 1])
            prevColWidth = prevCol.width();
            prevColPos = prevCol.position().left;
            leftPos = prevColPos + prevColWidth
        }
        that.css('left', leftPos+'px');
    })
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.locked{
  position:fixed;
}
```

However I do not recommend adding multi-listeners based on `id` !

It's better using `class="lockButton"` and then if you need the id you can take it.
So it's better:

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.lockButton'){
   var that = $(this),
   id = that[0].id;
   //... same code
}
```

Additionally since you didn't provide code and this is bad most people won't help you here if you don't provide any... so this code above might not work since I don't know your markup at all just guessing.

Comment: @kidwon thanks for taking time to help me. I've already edited my post and included my code.
And as you have expected, since I did not provided my code, it didn't work.